# Rails 3.2 redirection skips Create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a Rails 3 blog-style application, where I've got an **admin** namespace for backend purposes and a **controllers/admin** subfolder containing the respective **posts_controller.rb**.

So the page's root url is set to "admin/posts#index", and post creation works fine, except when I configure the routes file to redirect the user to root_url if he types "/admin/articles".

This is my routes file:

```
BlogDos::Application.routes.draw do
  # Index
  root to: "admin/posts#index"

  # If I uncomment these two lines below, the post#create function doesn't work. When I 
  # submit the "new post" form, the controller just skips the function entirelly and  
  # redirects me to admin/posts#index without creating the new post.
  # match "admin/posts" => redirect("/")
  # match "admin/posts/" => redirect("/")

  namespace :admin do
    resources :cpanel
    resources :posts do
      resources :comments, :only => [:create, :destroy]
    end
    root to: "cpanel#index"
  end
..
end
```

And this is my **posts_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @usuario = current_user
    @post = @usuario .posts.create(params[:post])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to article_dir_path(@post.year, @post.month, @post.slug), notice: 'Article was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: article_dir_path(@post.year, @post.month, @post.slug), status: :created, location: article_dir_path(@post.year, @post.month, @post.slug) }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Strangely, this only happens with the Create action, If i edit an article and update it, everything works fine. 
I have sorted out almost everything from looking at Rails tutorials and QA websites, except this little problem, I'm sure it is something rather simple, but i'm new to Rails and not very familiar with its routing mechanics yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form that creates the post submits to

```
/admin/posts
```

If you redirect that route to the index page, the controller action is never called.

Comment: I see, is there any workaround to solve this without removing the redirection feature entirely? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to redirect?

Comment: I don't want the site to have the /admin/posts path accesible, I just want it to be the root